# java - Read & determine number of integers

Tags: java

I am a new bee in java ... so I have an assignment and I am stuck can somebody help me

I have to write a program that reads an unspecified number of integers, determines how many positive and negative values have been read, and computes the total and average of the input values (not counting zero's). The program should end when the user inputs 0.

Sample run:

```
Enter an int value (the program exits if the input is 0: 1 3 -1 2 0 
The number of positives is 3
The number of negatives is 1
The total is 5
The average is 1.25
```

The thing which i wrote is ... The logic seems right but it does not work ...

The code that I wrote is

```
public class AverageNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {           
            int data = 0;
            int positive = 0;
            int negative = 0;
            int count = 0;


            while (data !=0) 
            {
                String strdata = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter the integer The input ends if the value is 0")  ;
                data = Integer.parseInt(strdata);
                if (data < 0 || data > 0){
                    count++;

                if (data >0)
                    positive++;
                else if (0<data)
                    negative++;
                count = count + data;
                count++;
            }


            String strOutput = "The number of positives is  " + positive;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, strOutput);
            strOutput = "The number of negatives is  " + negative;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, strOutput);
            strOutput = "The number of total is " + count ;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, strOutput);
            strOutput = "The number of average is " + count/data ;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, strOutput);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: You start with data = 0, so you never enter the while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

+1 for attempting and writing almost working code :)

As others have pointed out your code has few bugs which needs to be fixed.

1. Your assignment to data should happen at least once before entering 
   while(data) loop.
2. You don't need to check value of input before incrementing count, if
   it's 0 then you won't enter loop. Otherwise you will have to
   increment count anyways.
3. For calculating total and average you need to use one more variable

Are you using any IDE ? 
Use IDE (Eclipse is one of the best one) and debug your code step by step to check what's happening.
Google for how to use IDE and debug.

Below is working code for your reference.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class AverageNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {           
            int data = 0;
            int positive = 0;
            int negative = 0;
            int count = 0;
            int total = 0;
            double avg = 0;


            String strdata = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter the integer The input ends if the value is 0")  ;
            data = Integer.parseInt(strdata);

            while (data !=0) 
            {
                if (data >0) {
                    positive++;
                } else { 
                    negative++;
                }                    
                total = total + data;
                count++;

                strdata = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter the integer The input ends if the value is 0")  ;
                data = Integer.parseInt(strdata);
            }


            String strOutput = "The number of positives is  " + positive;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, strOutput);
            strOutput = "The number of negatives is  " + negative;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, strOutput);
            strOutput = "The number of total is " + count ;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, strOutput);
            avg = total * 1.0 /count ;
            strOutput = "The number of average is " + avg;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, strOutput);
            System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your while loop condition, you're checking if `data !=0` which returns false and the while loop code block doesn't execute, because the data is set to `int data = 0;` at the beginning of program.

There are 2 simple solutions to your problem:

1. Set data to something other than 0
2. Use `do...while` loop, see example below

   ```
   int data = 0;
   ...
   do{
       ...
   } while (data != 0);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Two errors here:

- Your loop will never execute, since on the initial run, `data == 0`.  You can fix this by asking the question early as opposed to later:

  ```
  String strdata = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter the integer The input ends if the value is 0")  ;
  int data = Integer.parseInt(strdata);
  ```

  Then, later in the loop (towards the bottom):

  ```
  strdata = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter the integer The input ends if the value is 0")  ;
  data = Integer.parseInt(strdata);
  ```
- Even *if* you were able to enter the loop, you'd get all positive number counts and no negative number counts.  The reason for this:    `data > 0` and `0 < data` are equivalent boolean statements.

  What you probably meant was this:

  ```
  if (data > 0) {
      positive++;
  } else if (data < 0) {
      negative++;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, initializing `data` to  is a problem, but see below for my advice there.

The other issue you're going to run into is you're having `count` do too much.

Assume `count` starts at 0 and the user enters 3.

In

```
if (data < 0 || data > 0){
     count++;
```

You're now at one, the you go into

```
count = count + data;
     count++;
```

And count goes up to 4, then ++ up to 5.

Even if you've got a 0 entered, you still alter count before breaking the loop.

Try something like Orel mentioned with having a sum int that just keeps track of the sum. Keep count only to count, and only the count++ at the very bottom, completely erase

```
if (data < 0 || data > 0){
      count++;
```

Instead, try something like this for the 0 check to prevent screwing with the whole thing:

```
while(true){
     String strdata = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter the integer The input ends if the value is 0")  ;
     data = Integer.parseInt(strdata);
     if (data == 0)
          break;
...
}
```

You could use a do/while here as well. This will allow you to initialize data to whatever (or nothing) that you like. Another thing, make sure that they value they enter is not null and is an int, your professor will definitely enter "sleirjwlfie" when prompted for a number because it's best practice to assume the user will break your program. So something in pseudo-code like:

```
while(true){
// get value from user
// if value is null OR value is not an int
     continue;
}
```

I'll let you sort out the how to there as to not kill the learning experience, but I know that kind of thing bit me in school more than once.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first problem is here.  You initialize data to 0:

```
int data = 0;
```

Then your loop condition checks for data != 0 :

```
while (data !=0) {
      ...
}
```

Since data is assigned 0, the loop is never entered.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a 'sum' int variable and change this line

count = count + data;

With this

sum +=  data;

Also change your `while-loop` to `do-while` loop.